# Does Samsung PM1735 1.6TB NVMe work on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvme

Does anyone know if Samsung PM1735 1.6GB or 3.2GB NVMe works on Ubuntu 20.04 (or other non paid Linux distro)?

I am intending to install it in Gigabyte X570 AORUS PRO motherboard but came across some data from lenovo and it wasn't listed as supported https://lenovopress.com/lp1312.pdf for their system (I know it's like comparing apples to oranges a bit but it got me thinking as it is not a typical consumer nvme). I don't need the advanced Virtualisation functionality and have chosen this storage for price to TBW ratio mainly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got confused upon finding the Lenovo PM1735 product guide. The Lenovo PM1735 is mostly a rebranded version of the Samsung PM1735, specified for usage in their own system. Their compatibility table means that Lenovo tested this drive against its own systems and provides technical support for that combination.

As a regular user you should probably go with the regular Samsung PM1735. A quick glance at their product page shows that its a NVME SSD for a PCIe slot. NVME is a standart bulk storage protocol and should be supported by all modern mainboards. The [Gigabyte X570 AORUS PRO product page](https://www.gigabyte.com/de/Motherboard/X570-AORUS-PRO-rev-10) shows two M.2 SSD slots with NVME support, so the board supports NVME.

Linux / Ubuntu also has NVME support for quite some time now, so you shouldn't expect any issues there.

**TL;DR:** Compatibility tables from OEMs like Lenovo specify hardware combinations they provide technical support for. That doesn't exclude the part from working in other systems. If you don't need their hardware or tech support, you should look at info from the manufacturer of the underlying hardware.